# Rails on windows not working -- ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished 5432 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm trying to learn rails but I'm having this problem to set up the connection between postgresql and rails. I have follow several tutorials but none of those have worked for me, as far as i know this issues has to do with the configuration i need to add on my database.yml.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the database running on a virtual machine, or in docker, or something?

Comment: You need to first start the postgres server on your Windows machine (or VM/container, depending on your postgres setup)

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure the username and password are accurate. You can just have them in the default block to avoid duplicating them in the development and test block and try again.

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
rails s
```